# How to convert server time to device time in iOS apps

Tags: ios, iphone, timezone, nsdateformatter

Working on an iOS application and a problem arises:

In the iOS app user will have tasks to be completed. In order to coordinate users from different timezone the task complete time is recorded using time on the server(America/Indiana/Indianapolis). That being said, we need a way to convert this server time into times on users' individual devices(say, a user from LA and another from Hawaii).

I understand that I need to user NSTimeFormatter or something related to that but after wrestling with it this morning I still cannot get it to work. Given that this should be done a lot in app development I am seeking for some help!

So, how to convert a string fetched from Mysql(e.g. 2014-02-16 14:00:20. in the time zone of America/Indiana/Indianapolis) to local timezone on users' devices?

Thanks guys!

Comment: What about getting the time in milliseconds from server then get the time in milliseconds from device then do whatever you want?

Answer (score 0):

To keep things simple you use get UTC time from the server so you only have one timezone conversion to worry about (client side).

You can either get that in some kind of standard format you can use NSDateFormatter to unwind, or as Idan suggested consider getting the time in milliseconds since 1970 (which is a UNIX standard that applies to iPhone and server alike) and then just convert that value into a NSDate which will display appropriately for the current time zone.